# How to kill/exit/close any app completely? EXPERT ADVICE

Tags: battery

Is there any way to kill a app completely **JUST** like Windows 7 where i can exit any application completely or prevent autostart by going into "msconfig".

How to kill/close an app so it does not bother my battery/cpu till i open it again **JUST** like windows.

I have root access. SUGGEST software to do such thing keeping in mind that what i am trying to achieve here something like install the app it will never bother you unless you open it just like windows 7/xp...

I used **greenify** in non root **didnt** helped.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details) – so "SUGGEST software to do such thing" doesn't fit here. For where that might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). Here, please be open to alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is force stop the app.  You don't need root or anything for it.  Go into your app drawer, find the app, tap and hold it just as if you were adding it to your home screen and drag it to the top where it says app info.  Then just hit force stop.  No data will be intercepted when you force stop it and it wont start running on its own, the only way to start it is by opening it.

Comment: Keep in mind that some apps may launch when certain events are called/broadcasted. GCM can also launch apps to handle GCM messages.

Comment: i use greenify to freeze every app which i installed..still i cannot get the battery life as i get after a hard reset (with no app installed).

installing app and exiting it also force stop wont solve the battery issue....this is the reason why i wrote expert advise...

SCREEN ONTIME:
with no apps installed = 11.5 hrs....
with all apps installed and all hibernated by greeenify = 8 hrs

Comment: The reason you don't get the same battery life is because it isn't just the apps that drain battery.  A whole  ton of things come into play when it comes to battery drain, and hard resetting just eliminates them.  One of them being storage space.  If you've noticed, having a ton of apps that take up almost all storage space really slows down any task.  Even if the apps aren't running, they're taking up space and therefore effecting the battery.

Comment: nope space does not eat battery...i double checked it...after hard reset i copied 3 4movies and songs to internal memory only 1gb internal left...same battery life....

Comment: It's not a matter of size alone. A bajillion of small files whose size sums up to 1GB will kill your device more effectively than a single 4K video. It's the number of accesses to disk which matters.

Comment: so you mean to say my 8 apps are eating battery with greenifed hibernation  all the time (coz i use them occasionally)

only two apps i use chrome+whatsapp and lock the screen after hibernating every time....

android sucks then i stil remember installing n number of in a symbian device doesnt effect battery unless you use them....

Answer (score 0):

You need to Force Stop the app in settings
Settings > Apps > The app name > Force Stop !
This will close it until you open it again !